# perl regular expression for inserting a character without using functions at certain points

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a script that checks to see that a string has 9 characters. This string will be divided into 3 sets/groups. First group having three numbers, second group having two numbers and third having four numbers. I want to capture these using parentheses and print them out. I wrote the following thinking it was 100% correct but it is not working:

```
my $numbers =  123456789;

( my $three, my $two, my $four ) = ( $numbers =~ /([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})/);
print "$three-$two-$four";
```

It prints `123-4567`

From my understanding the above regex says, "a digit between 0-9 with 3 repetitions and capture the value, a digit between 0-9 with 2 repetitions and capture the value, a digit between 0-9 with 4 repetitions and capture the value, and nothing else. There cannot be any other chars before or after the numbers."

Comment: works just fine for me.  perhaps you were running an earlier version of the program by accident, to get that output?  is your real input any different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the digits start at the start of the string and end at the end of the string, otherwise `1234567891` will match.

```
my ($first, $second, $third) = $number =~ /^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})\z/
   or die("Invalid input\n");

print "$first-$second-$third\n";
```

Comment: lets say the 123456789 is as follows, "1234567891" if it is greater than 9 it is invalid and an error should be shown. I thought the $ was for the end of a string.

Comment: Right, that's the main change I made. /// `\z` is end of string. `$` (without `/m`) means `(?=\n?\z)`.

Comment: I am a little new to this. I have only read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Regular-expressions and am not familiar with what \z is.

Comment: `/^1234$/` will match `"1234"`, but it will also match `"1234\n"`